# mysql_fetch_array() not displaying all results

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a database with a calendar table (each row represents one day) with 4 years of rows (2012, 2013, 2014, 2015). I use the column name calyear for the year.

I use the following code to find values for distinct years then display it:

```
$year = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT calyear FROM calendar");

while($yeararray = mysql_fetch_array($year))
{
 echo($yeararray['calyear']."<br />");
}
```

The problem is it only displays the years 2013, 2014, 2015 even though when I use

```
echo(mysql_num_rows($year);
```

it displays the value 4 which I take to mean all 4 years are there. I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong with this.

**EDIT********

Thanks for your suggestions but I found the problem and it was my own stupidity.

I had the `$year` query at the top of the page and the While loop later on (where I needed it). I'd earlier put `$yeararray = mysql_fetch_array($year)` directly underneath the `$year` so I had it twice on the page, and when I removed the redundant one at the top the code worked fine.

Thanks and sorry!

Comment: maybe the database is returning those three years plus `null` in the fourth row? it's the only thing I can think of given your description.

Comment: use var_dump to check whats in variables ...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the 4th value is a null or blank, and when you echo it, you simply don't see it.

Do a `desc calendar` and find out what default value is set for column calyear.

Then do a `select count(*) from calendar where calyear is null` or a `select count(*) from calendar where calyear = <whatever the default you've set>` to see if it's a blank or null value that's being picked up.

Comment: But if I take away the While loop and just have echo($yeararray['calyear']) it displays only 2012. 2012 is being lost somewhere when I put it in the While loop